# Bed frame no longer holding

Tags: bolts, bedroom

Is there a way to fix this?

Every time I tighten the bolts with an hour wrench it becomes undone. I just noticed that it is very loose now.

[image]

Comment: It would help if we could see the bolts & how they fasten, not just the guide dowels.

Comment: What's an 'hour wrench'? Are the bolt heads on the outside of the legs? More pics, please!

Comment: probably allen wrench with autocorrection on voice to text.

Answer (score 1):

If they are wooden dowels, which they look like, then taking it apart and using wood glue should work.

Need to keep it tight together until the glue dries.

Clean the holes of any dust/dirt in them.

EDIT  If there are bolts/screws that you use a wrench/driver on, the holes are probably stripped and not holding the threads.

If the holes are just wood, the usual fix is to place toothpicks and wood glue into the holes.  For larger holes/screws, you can drill out the hole to fit a wood dowel in and make a new hole for the threads.

If it is a bolt, then there should be a nut in the wood.  If the threads are stripped then replacement of the bolt and nut is usually the best.  Pictures of the screws/bolts will help.

Comment: It's doubtful they were ever anything more than locating pins.

Comment: If they're particle board, a solution may be more involved.

Answer (score 0):

I typically glue one side of the dowels so I can still take it apart later.

It does look like whatever fastener is in the post has pulled particle board from the rail.  You can just pull the fastener out and get a longer fastener that will drive further into the rail.  a #8 3" wood screw will probably do well, I'd predrill with a drill bit slightly smaller than the #3 diameter.

If you don't care about taking it apart then you can just wood glue both sides of the dowels and leave it in place with some weight or a screw holding it together till the glue sets.